# utf-8 German Umlaut has two different bytecode representations

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8

In utf-8, the german alphabet "ö" has two form, the one is:
b'\xc3\xb6', the other is b'o\xcc\x88'

Following code is in python 3.6.3

```
In [1]: b'\xc3\xb6'.decode('utf-8')
Out[1]: 'ö'

In [2]: b'o\xcc\x88'.decode('utf-8')
Out[2]: 'ö'
```

This will cause the problem for searching words with "ö". How can I convert the second form to first form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run it through [Unicode normalization](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize). Use `NFC` as the *form*.

Comment: `0xC3 0xB6` is the UTF-8 representation of Unicode codepoint `U+00F6 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS`, whereas `0x6F 0xCC 0x88` is the UTF-8 representation of Unicode codepoints `U+006F LATIN SMALL LETTER O` and `U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS` together.  Normalizing with NFC will convert `U+006F U+0308` into `U+00F6`, whereas normalizing with NFD will do the opposite.